# Troubleshooting Open3D Point Cloud Display in Docker on Linux

Tags: python, docker, open3d

How can I run it?
I'm trying to display a point cloud in GUI using docker, but I get this warming and can't do it.
I am using linux.

```
[Open3D WARNING] GLFW Error: X11: Failed to open display :0
myapp_1 | [Open3D WARNING] Failed to initialize GLFW
myapp_1 | [Open3D WARNING] [DrawGeometries] Failed creating OpenGL window.
```

Dockerfile

```
# Specify base image
FROM python:3.10

# Install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    x11-apps \
    x11-utils \
    x11-xserver-utils \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Configure X11
ENV DISPLAY=:0

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy application source code
COPY . /app
# Install Open3D
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

This Dockerfile begins with a base image of Python 3.10.
It then updates the package list and installs X11-related packages required for GUI applications within the Docker container.
The ENV DISPLAY=:0 line sets the DISPLAY environment variable to :0, which specifies the X11 display to use.
docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services: myapp: myapp: myapp: myapp: myapp: myapp: myapp
  . myapp: .
    build: .
    volumes: .
      - :/home/iplslam/point_cloud_to_voxel:/app
    environment: .
      - DISPLAY=:0
    ports: .
      - "8000:8000"
    # Mount X11 socket to container (allows connection to host's X11 server)
    volumes:.
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.
    # Grant privileges to processes running in the container
    security_opt:.
      - "seccomp=unconfined"
    environment:.
      - DISPLAY=:0
```

In the docker-compose.yml file, a Docker Compose service named myapp is defined.
The build: . line specifies that the Docker image should be built from the current directory, where the Dockerfile is located.
The volumes section mounts the current directory (where your project code is) to the /app directory within the container.
The environment section sets the DISPLAY environment variable to :0 to specify the X11 display.
The ports section maps port 8000 on the host to port 8000 in the container.
The second volumes section mounts the X11 socket from the host to allow the container to connect to the host's X11 server.
The security_opt section is used to specify the security options for the container.
The second environment section sets the DISPLAY environment variable again for redundancy.

Comment: You have multiple `volumes:` blocks, and different YAML parsers can handle those differently.  The first one that mounts host content over `/app` should be unnecessary; does just deleting that help?  (If you want to run code on the host against the host display, you may find it much easier to not introduce Docker into the setup.)